# using file and awk to add file extensions

Tags: bash, awk

Ok, this was probably a poorly worded title, but I wasn't quite sure how to write it.  What I'm trying to do is go through a large list of files (without extensions) and determine what they are, then add an appropriate extension.

I discovered a really handy utility for linux called 'file' to help out with this.  I know python syntax much better than bash & awk, but I had a lot of issues getting the 3rd party "python-magic" module working on my machine so instead of wasting time with that I spent my time trying to write it in bash/awk.

I believe I'm really close, but something is still off with my syntax and i'm not sure what.

Here is the code:

```
for i in *;
    do file $i | awk '{
        switch ($2) {
        case $2 == 'TIFF':
            mv $i "$i.tif"

        case $2 == 'PDF':
            mv $i "$i.pdf"

        case $2 == 'ASCII':
            mv $i "$i.txt"

        case $2 == 'Rich':
            mv $i "$i.rtf"

        case $2 == 'gzip':
            mv $i "$i.gz"
        }
    }';
done
```

The syntax errors i'm getting on some test txt files are:

```
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:         case $2 == TIFF:
awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error
```

I saw some other interesting methods of doing file renames with awk and sed, but at least in my mind, using in combination with 'file', this seems like the best approach for my skill level.

If anyone could help me troubleshoot these awk syntax errors, that would be awesome.  Or, in a more generic help sense, if you know of a better method of accomplishing this task, please share  :)

**EDIT:**

I made the changes suggested (fixed quotes, removed comparison operator from each case, added breaks).  Now the script runs without error, but none of the files are changed.  They are all still extensionless.  My test files are all ASCII and so should be renamed to have '.txt' appended to the end.

To test and verify i'm pulling the right field with awk I ran this little test:

```
$ file test2 | awk '{printf $2}'
ASCII
```

So $2 is the file type.   Any ideas on why it's not working?

Comment: Also, you are trying to execute the `mv` program as if it were an `awk` command.

Comment: Actually, most of your `awk` script looks like shell.

Comment: @chepner so I take it that's not valid syntax.  Would I be better of doing an printf contruct of the mv command and appending it to a new file?  The thought that by the end of the for loop, i have a file that's essentially a big list of mv commands that i could run as a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `awk` here:

```
for i in *; do
    filetype=$(file $i)
    case $filetype in
        *TIFF*) ext="tif"
                ;;
        *PDF*) ext="pdf"
               ;;
        *ASCII*) ext="txt"
                 ;;
        *Rich*) ext="rtf"
                ;;
        *gzip*) ext="gz"
                ;;
    esac
    echo mv "$i" "$i.$ext"
done
```

When the output looks like a safe set of commands to run, you can remove the `echo` to actually execute the `mv` commands.

Comment: Ah yeah, this looks much better.  It wasn't working at first, then i realized (by looking at @devnull 's post) that it was just missing the 'do' statement after the 'for' statement.  If you edit and add the 'do' i'll mark as best answer.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: I thought that looked a little bare :) Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Since your awk script is enclosed in single quotes, use double quotes inside awk for literal strings.

So

```
case $2 == 'TIFF'
```

should be replaced with:

```
case "TIFF"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax should be like this:

```
case "TIFF":
    mv $i "$i.pdf"
    break
```

1. Your `switch` statement already references the `$2`, so don't repeat this everywhere.
2. As anubhava said, watch your quote nesting.
3. Without the `break` it just going to fall through and run the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  That makes a lot of sense now.  I've made the changes and the script runs without error on my test files, but no extensions are added.  I added an edit to the original post with more details

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using the shell `case` construct instead.  The following might work for you:

```
for i in *;
    do
        type=$(file "$i" | awk '{print $2}')
        case "$type" in
        TIFF)
            mv $i "$i.tif"
;;
        PDF)
            mv $i "$i.pdf"
;;
        ASCII)
            mv $i "$i.txt"
;;
        Rich)
            mv $i "$i.rtf"
;;
        gzip)
            mv $i "$i.gz"
;;
        esac
done
```